# Use the marketplace test kit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I want to use the Marketplace test kit to test an application I made.
I changed the building configuration to release and I build the application, but I'm faced with this error: ***XAP Package not up to date. Build the application in Release Configuration before you run the Marketplace Test Kit.***

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Express, is it why it's not working?

Comment: Have you tried `Build` > `Rebuild Solution`?

Comment: Yes I have, but it didn't work. Even I build and save everything and close Visual Studio, and when I launch it again, it changes back from release to Build, I mean the configuration.

Comment: In your project, try deleting the `Bin` and `Obj` folder, `Rebuild` and try again?